# Capturing scrot command output with su

Tags: shell-script, su

I want to capture the name of an image file created with [scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot). I can capture the filename like this:

```
$ image=$(scrot -s -e 'echo $n')
$ echo $image
2018-09-07-140419_185x76_scrot.png
```

I need to do that via `su`:

```
$ image=$(su someuser -c "scrot -s -e 'echo $n'")
```

However, `image` is empty.

I think this syntax is correct - this works:

```
$ greeting=$(su someuser -c "echo 'hello, world'")
$ echo $greeting
hello, world
```

I am not sure why this isn't working with `scrot`. I presume it something to do with how `scrot` launches its subshell - I guess it doesn't propagate its output?

Comment: Are you sure `scrot` is not simply failing because an appropriate `DISPLAY` is not set in the `su` environment and/or `someuser` doesn't have authority to access it?

Comment: No, the `scrot` part works just fine and the file is created successfully (did have to set `DISPLAY` etc for that to work however, so a good question to ask!)

Comment: btw, it would be a better idea to run scrot via "ssh -X someuser@localhost scrot ..."  (with public key auth, so you don't have to type in a password) instead of having to give 'someuser' access to your display.

Comment: It's `root` issuing the `su` so no password is required. The user switch is needed to execute in the context of the user that the desktop belongs to otherwise `scrot` and other things I do later don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$n" inside the -c command with be expanded by the outer shell, not by scrot. You should escape it:

```
$ image=$(su someuser -c "scrot -s -e 'echo \$n'")
```

Comment: escaping, yes! I tried that unsuccessfully but your answer made be look at it again. Because of exactly what I am doing, I needed a double-escape: `scrot -s -e 'echo \\$n'`. But escaping is the reason it wasn' working, so - accepted answer.